# Sitecore SBOS Module Click-through measurement

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I installed SBOS accelerators version 1.2 to have click-through reporting for Multi variant testing.

I use Sitecore 7.0 Mvc and the clicks are not registered on the report.

Is Mvc not supported in version 1.2? 
Does anyone know what I can do to make it work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

SBOS 1.2 does not support MVC. This is mentioned in the comments on the Sitecore Marketplace. It's supported by 2.0 only.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/SBOS_Accelerators.aspx

Have a nice day!
Gert.

Comment: Thank you Gert.
In my eyes it was not clear in the documentation.